# Two Dimensional ArrayList of tiles

Tags: java, tile

I have a array right now,

```
    static int[][] map = new int[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
```

This code places tiles on the map:

```
for (int y = 18; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
            map[x][y] = STONE;
        }

    }

    for (int y = 18; y < 19; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
            map[x][y] = GRASS;
        }

    }

    for (int y = 19; y < 20; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
            map[x][y] = DIRT;
        }

    }
```

And here is how I render them:

```
for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
            switch (map[x][y]) {
            case CLEAR:
                air.draw(x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
                break;
            case STONE:
                stone.draw(x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
                break;
            case GRASS:
                grass.draw(x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
                break;
            case DIRT:
                dirt.draw(x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I convert this code to replace the array map with a 2 dimensional arraylist so I can remove these tiles like minecraft?

Comment: Yes, so I can add and remove tiles. Wouldn't I have to do it this way? Or should I use a array to render and then an arraylist to access them? I honestly am very confused...

Comment: Why these is loop, if runs only once: `for (int y = 18; y < 19; y++) {` and `for (int y = 19; y < 20; y++) {`? **You can directly use the index instead.** e.g. only one loop as : `for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
            map[x][18] = GRASS;
        }`

Comment: @YogendraSingh Oh yeah I guess I could, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> map = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

Basically you are create an array list of array lists which in turn are lists of integers.

Comment: But how would I access both the variable lists so I can place the tiles down? Right now I use `map[x][y]` to place the tiles. How would I go about it with an arraylist?

Comment: You can use map.get(x).get(y).

Comment: @user1724140 That doesn't work, it just says the left hand side needs to be a variable....

Comment: replace it with map.get(x).set(y, STONE); oops sorry late at night ;/ Also note that this is used usually to modify the element at that index..If you are inserting the elements at the correct order by using a for loop (Like in the above code), just use the add method. map.get(x).add(STONE);

Comment: @user1724140 ok thanks that's lots of help, now how do I get the coordinates of the tiles so I can use my switch statement and draw the tiles?

Comment: Oh sorry I actually meant this part: `switch (map[x][y])`.

Comment: see edit :) Tell me if you dont understand something. glad to help

Comment: Wow you are amazing! Last error I think, when I run it, I get this: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0` for this line of code: `map.get(x).set(y, STONE);` EDIT: fixed it, but now the tiles aren't rendering :/

Comment: I think its giving you that error because Stone must be constant. When you declare Stone, do it like this: `final int STONE = 1;` Note that by using the final keyword I am declaring a constant, which means that during my program, STONE's value cannot change, but must always be 1.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19364/discussion-between-opiop65-and-user1724140)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would do this with a single `List`, and use math to determine which tile I am looking at.

```
List<Integer> map = new ArrayList<Integer>(WIDTH * HEIGHT);
```

To find the index you are interested in, you could do this:

```
//note that this is 0 based

//find (0,0)
map.get(0 * WIDTH  + 0);

//find (0,1)
map.get(0 * WIDTH  + 1);

//find (1,0)
map.get(1 * WIDTH  + 0);

//In general
//find (x,y)
map.get(x * WIDTH  + y);
```

You could then utilize the same math to set values into the `List`.

```
map.set(x * WIDTH + y, STONE);
```

Comment: Wow this makes sense, so I would use `map.set(x * WIDTH + y, STONE);` in my for loops? EDIT: so what would STONE be set to now? Right now it is an int set to 1, do I need to make it an arraylist to now?

Comment: Now my switch statement doesn't work, it throws this error: `Cannot switch on a value of type ArrayList<Integer>. Only convertible int values, strings or enum variables are permitted`

Comment: `switch` statements cannot take in arbitrary objects, as the compiler warning states.  You will need to do something like this:  `switch(map.get(x * WIDTH + y).intValue())`

Comment: Thanks, however `.intValue()` doesn't solve the problem. Thanks for all the help though!